# keydown event not working in opngl langauge

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

How i can use keydown event in opengl language, here i paste some partial code but it not working, anyone help to fix this code.

```
bool keypress(int key) {
          return texelFetch(texture2D, ivec2(key,2),0).x != 0.0;  }
```

// in above code texture2D was iChannel0 so i change to texture2D according to my script but i think i mistake is this line

```
const int k = 17;      // 17 for CTRL

void main()
{ 
        vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
        vec2 uv = p / resolution.xy;
    
    float blend = 1.9-pow(1.5*cos(time/8.0),5.0);
    
        vec3 cul = texture2D(media, uv).rgb;
        vec3 col = texture2D(media, uv).rgb;
         
          if (keypress(k)) col = mix(cul,col,blend); 
         gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

When i press CTRL key it will not execute this ==>>  col = mix(cul,col,blend);
I don't know where i mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Shaders do not execute in any place where "keypress" is a thing that happens. Shaders are not like HTML or CSS properties in Javascript, where changing a property updates the view. You render something, and that rendering causes shaders to be executed. If you want to change how things are rendered, you must *explicitly* render them again.

If you want something to be rendered differently based on a keypress, then your keypress Javascript routine needs to set some state and tell your code to re-render the scene. The rendering code will use this state to adjust shader uniforms or other data accessible to your rendering system and then draw everything again.

For example:

```
const int k = 17;
```

That is a constant; hence the keyword `const`. It doesn't change. Ever. It's always 17. If you want to pass a value to the shader that represents a key, you would need a uniform, UBO, or something of the like. Certainly not a *constant*.

Comment: script is already running and rendering, but i want when i pres CTRL key i will mix both textures with blend so the problem is keypress event is not working. otherwise if i use this code [ col = mix(cul,col,blend); ] without keypess it works pefectly but i want it works on keypress

Comment: @smallbee: As I thought I made clear, shaders don't know anything about keys. They only know what you tell them. I see nothing in your shader that would allow it to be informed about any keypresses (and of course, none of the code that would inform it, since you haven't posted any).

Comment: yea i didn't post the full code, i just post the partial code for just keypress function, but it not working, i copy few lines of code of keypress event/function from here https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dKyzm     ...and then add it to my code. but it still not working.

Comment: @smallbee check your key map texture if its changing on key hits or not ...